# Riddle: Where am I at?

Tags: riddle

I woke up this morning with a bit of amnesia, so I need help identifying where I'm at.

In the last 10 minutes I saw a pyramid,  the Eiffel Tower, the Statue of Liberty and a pirate ship.

Hint: _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _

Comment: even driving the pyramid is more than ten minutes from the pirate ship

Comment: Depends on what time you do the drive :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no pirate ship in [Minimundus](http://www.minimundus.at/en/interactive/picture-archive.html) so you must be in Las Vegas.

Answer (score 4):

Another valid answer would be: [Legoland](http://legoland.com/)

Comment: That's a pretty good guess. OP has already accepted another answer but I like this one and it fits.

Comment: Doesn't fit the hint though ;) up vote nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

> Internet

I was thinking of particular websites, but they don't fit your hint (actually a major restriction)